# Win10 1607 LTSB - Change Start Menu Layout for Existing Profile (Appx)

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-10-universal, sccm, windows-10-desktop

We have a bunch of business critical Win 10 tablets (imagine being used by Ambulance drivers when they are out on a call). As part of upgrading the main app used on these devices, I need to run a PowerShell script to install a disgusting and foul appx app as the shared user account.

This bit is fine, however, using the same script I have to update the user's start menu layout to remove the old icon and add the new icon (new GUID and new Publisher) to the start menu.

We can't do this manually as we have a lot of tablets and it's not feasible. I can't do it as GPO because I can't have the script remove the old app, install the new app, but then the start menu icon points to the old uninstalled app. It needs to all be done in one step.

Has anyone managed this?